# How do I send a message to someone mentioned from a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How could I send a message to a user that was mentioned in a message?
Here is what i tried so far:

[image: self-explanatory, please tell me what is wrong]

Comment: What does your picture have to do with your question?

Comment: Troubleshooting obviously :P

Comment: Not obvious. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should edit your question and add the new title to the question

Comment: You should not be using sendMessage. It's deprecated in the latest version.

Comment: @EliR I don't care tbh it works fine

Comment: @AnimReverted That’s a bad thing to do. Use .send instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `message.mentions.members.first()`.

This returns the first member *mentioned* in the message.

Documentation: [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), [Mentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions), [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection)